# How to add spring state machine listener on entity creation?

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I have working state machine transition listeners configured: an action is invoked when entity's state changes from A to B. Now I need to invoke an action when entity is created with initial state A. How could I do this?

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<State, Event> states) throws Exception {
    states.withStates().initial(State.A).states(EnumSet.allOf(State.class));
}

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<State, Event> transitions) throws Exception {
    transitions
    
      // this does not work
      .withExternal()
      .event(Event.CREATE).source(null).target(State.A)
      .action(action())
      //
      
      .and()
      .withExternal()
      .event(Event.COMPLETE).source(State.A).target(State.B)
      .action(action());
}

private Action<State, Event> action() {
    return stateContext -> {
        final Entity entity = (Entity) stateContext.getMessageHeader(ENTITY);
        log.info(entity.getState());
    };
}

....
enum StateMachineHeader {
  ENTITY
}
....
```

Comment: can you share the code for your listener implementation?

Comment: added the declaration

Comment: thx, another question just to clarify. You need to invoke an action when state A is entered, which is your initial state, right? I did not understand very well the "entity" part

Comment: i need to invoke an action when entity (e.g. notification object) is created.
in another class the object is created:
`Notification n = new Notification();
n.setState(State.A);
repository.save(n);`

and now i want to trigger an action via state machine transition configuration. ofc i could invoke it just after `repository.save(n)`, but for design purposes its better to trigger the action in one class if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The framework allows us to configure how actions are triggered in two ways. The usual is via transitions (where you show an example that does not work because it doesn't have a valid source. Another way is to configure entry/exit actions in the state configuration.

Can you try the configuration bellow to see if it satisfies your requirement?

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<State, Event> states) throws Exception {
    states.withStates().initial(State.A, action()).states(EnumSet.allOf(State.class));
```

Comment: adding the action param to `initial` does not work. i have also tried to add other declarations before 'initial' like `state/stateDoFunction/stateEntry/stateEntryFunction`, no result...

Comment: please define does not work. Are you saying that the action was not hit when the machine got to the state that defined it?

Comment: yes, the action was not invoked after object creation

Comment: object creation is unrelated to machine transitions. You need to instanciate a machine that has initial state configured for specific entry action. This is the moment action will be trigerred. There is not such thing as automatic state join when custom unrellated object is manulally updated

Comment: does it mean that my case isn't possible to solve with transitions? if i want an action to be triggered just after the object creation, i need to create it with some `State.beforeA`, save the object and then change the state from `beforeA` to `A`, right?

Comment: the part i'm not understanding is what you mean by "object creation". Spring state machine is a framework that helps you control a workflow by using a state machine. The machine has a list of possible states that are reachable when an event is sent to the machine, events trigger the transitions and each transition is handled by what is called an "action". When you create an "object of type state machine", you will get to that initial configured action. But if you create a random object (in your case, the Entity class) the framework is not aware the relationship between state machine and entity

Comment: unless you're talking about something like the Persist Recipe https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#statemachine-recipes-persist
@taran2la